# Calling user input from main method into another method

Tags: java, arrays, input, methods, return-value

Hello I am new to Java and need a bit of help. My apologies if I get some of the verbiage wrong. I am prompting a user to input 2 numbers in my main method and I need to return those two numbers into a int [] method with 2 parameters already set. So I have something along the lines of this

```
public static int[] getnum (int a , int b) {

int [] z = {a,b}

return z;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner = new scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

a = scanner.netInt();

System.out.println("Please enter another number.");

b = scanner.netInt();

getnum(a,b); // I don't know how to pass a and b into my getnum 

}
```

I have tried to do getnum (a,b); but I don't know how to get that back up to my getnum method. I feel like its simple but I can't wrap my brain around it I have been at this for a bit now.

So I already have parameters I have to use in getnum I need to have a and b in my main method fill in for x and y in my get num method so I can return z. Any direction or advice is much appreciated. I hope I explained that clearly.

Comment: I suggest that you continue to read Java tutorials. Specifically, you should find one that explains how to use a method. We say that you "call" a method to use it. So I suggest googling something like "java tutorial method call" to find more info.

Comment: You say "I have tried to do getnum (a,b); ". Where did you put this in your code? What happened when you did this? Did you get any errors? If so what were they? If not, what was the output and what do you want it to be instead? If you need help with that attempt, [edit] your code to show it.

Comment: how are you calling `println()` method or `netInt()` method?

Comment: Thank you! I see the input when I printed the arrays.to string. I tried to call the whole arrays.toString (getnum); from the getnum and then try to return getnum but  it wants me to initialize it all over again. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, when coding give your methods and variables names something that is a wee bit more meaningful than just `getnum`, `a`, `b`, and `z`. The remainder of this answer will be based from the `getIntArray()` method shown below:

```
public static int[] getIntArray(int element1, int element2) {
    int[] intArray = { element1, element2 };
    return intArray;
}
```

This method is exactly the same as your method with the sole purpose of taking the two supplied arguments passed to the method and placing them into an integer (int) Array and returning that array:

For your use case, the `getIntArray()` method stores the integer values (which the User has entered into the console window) into an integer array of type ***int*** for use later on in your code. This method would be called after the User has successfully supplied the required numerical data which is placed into the integer variables `a` and `b` like this:

```
int[] myArray = getIntArray(a, b);
```

After this call to the `getIntArray()` method you might want to prove the values are in the array as indexed elements by also adding this code line after that call:

```
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

or by using a looping mechanism perhaps like this standard `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(myArray[i]);
}
```

---

**As per your comment:**

> I tried to call the whole Arrays.toString (getnum);

If you want to call the `getIntArray()` method directly within the [Arrays.toString()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm) method then you must also supply the required arguments `a` and `b` (provided by User) for the respective `getIntArray()` method parameters `element1` and `element2`. For example, this will work just fine:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIntArray(a, b));
```

Because the `getIntArray()` method contains required parameters you **must** supply the arguments (values) to satisfy that requirement for those specific method parameters otherwise an exception (error) will occur.

---

**For Fun:**

Let's assume that you want to deal with more than just two integer values. Let's say you want the User to supply 10 integer values (or any number of integers for that matter) and then call the `getIntArray()` method to return all those values within an integer array:

```
int myArray = getIntArray(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

The Console will display:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

indicating that each of the supplied values are indeed contained as indexed elements within the array named `myArray`.

How is this possible you ask? The parameters for the `getIntArray()` method have been replaced with what is called [**Varargs** Notation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter. The three periods (**...**  known as an ellipsis) after the parameter's type indicate that the argument may be passed as an array **or as a sequence of arguments** delimited with a comma. Varargs can be used ***only*** in the final argument position **or** as the ***only*** method parameter. See the new method below:

```
public static int[] getIntArray(int... elementValues) {
    return elementValues;
}
```

This method still does the very same thing your method does with one exception, you can pass as many arguments as you like just as long as each argument is separated by a comma. In reality, you don't have to pass any argument at all however, in this particular use case, you will be returned an empty (null) array. Just something to play with.

Answer (score -1):

Parameters are the right step. In your getnum (this doesn't mean anything) method, act as if x and y are local variables. Then, in the main method, give x and y a value when you call the method.
Here is what your code can look like:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FILENAME {
  public static int[] getnum(int x, int y) {
    int[] z = { x, y };
    return z;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Java is case sensitive!

    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

    int a = scanner.netInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter another number.");

    int b = scanner.netInt();

    getnum(a, b); // You call the method with parameters.
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't think I phrased my question properly so I edited my code. I was trying to make it concise and not putting the whole lot of my code here but after I get the input values from the user for a and b in my main method how would I pass those back to my getnum method?

Comment: So the first input is int a, and the second input is int b. Later, we call the `getnum` method, and inside the parameters, we put a and b (the user input). Does that make sense?

Comment: it does I forgot to reply! TYSM for all your help!